# PowerBI Slicer create range

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the university league tables dataset. Two columns: University, and Tariff Points.

When I select a university on a slicer I want to a table which displays universities within 10% range of the tariff number. So say I select Oxford University and it was 200, I want a table to display all universities that fall between 180-220.

Is there a DAX function that could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new measure with the 10% logic with a data output of true/false. Then use this measure to filter your visual where the output is true. You will need two unrelated tables to do this, one for your slicer selection, and one for your output visual.

```
ABS( 
    DIVIDE( 
        SELECTEDVALUE( output[tariff_points] ), 
        SELECTEDVALUE( input[tariff_points] ) 
    ) - 1
) <= 0.1
```